# jQuery inArray always return -1

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Can't figure out why this always returns -1

```
var statuses = [5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 23];
var posted_status = $('select[name=\'order_status_id\']').val();
alert($.inArray(posted_status, statuses));
```

No matter which of the numbers in the array are set in posted_status the inArray method always returns -1 or not found. ie: posted_status = 18 or 5 or 12 returns -1 not found.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have numerical values in the array and is searching for a string so parse the value of `posted_status` to an int using parseInt() or the unary plus operator

```
var statuses = [5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 23];
var posted_status = $('select[name=\'order_status_id\']').val();
alert($.inArray(parseInt(posted_status, 10), statuses));
alert($.inArray(+posted_status, statuses)); //using unary plus short and easy
```

[Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

> indexOf compares searchElement to elements of the Array using [strict
>   equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators) (the same method used by the ===, or triple-equals,
>   operator).

[ES 5](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.14)

> indexOf compares searchElement to the elements of the array, in
>   ascending order, using the internal Strict Equality Comparison
>   Algorithm ([11.9.6](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6)), and if found at one or more positions, returns the
>   index of the first such position; otherwise, -1 is returned.

Comment: JavaScript type coercion doesn't apply here?

Comment: @JasonSperske no it doesn't

Comment: Of course ... after I posted I thought it might be a casting issue. Thank you.  I'll accept your answer as soon as it let's me.

Answer (score 2):

The .val() function returns a string, that's why it doesn't find it.
You should parse the value:

```
$.inArray(parseInt(posted_status, 10), statuses)
```